# Printing after assert with unittesting in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to print the item that rose as exception when I run my unit tests. For example:

```
def test_string(self):
   my_str = "new string"
   self.assertTrue(len(my_str) == 5)
```

This is a very simplified example but it shows what I am trying to achieve. I want, in that case, for the test to print "new string" after I get 'F'.

In regular `assert` I can achieve that by doing:

```
assert (len(my_str) == 5), "new string"
```

But when using `unittest` it won't work.

Is there a way to do that with `unittest` ?

Comment: this is an example ofc

Comment: For starters, use `self.assertEqual(len(my_str), 5)`. Also, use pytest if you can, then you can write regular asserts and it'll still show you the failing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 self.assertTrue(len(str) == 5, msg="new string")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue